# Collision detection between multiple picture boxes?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015, collision-detection

Alright, so i just can't seem to figure out a way to put in place some type of collision detection between several picture boxes.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/16dKe.png

As you can see from the image above, within my game, i need to ensure that none of the picture boxes can move passed each other.

The only way i can think of doing this is by writing out an if statement for every picture box where it would check whether it intersects with the bounds of the other picture boxes, but this would be quite tedious and redundant.

So what i did was this:

```
private void Block_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
     PictureBox block = sender as PictureBox;

     if (block.Bounds.IntersectsWith(block.Bounds))
     {
         dragging = false;
     }
}
```

So as you can see, all of the picture boxes use this MouseMove event handler and the properties of the current picture box which is moving is captured by the variable 'block'. So, what i tried with this was to check if 'block' intersects with another 'block'. However, this would just check if the current moving 'block' is intersecting with itself (which it is) so it would just end up stopping the 'block' from moving.

So, if anyone can help me create a way in which a picture box would come to a stop when its about to collide with another picture box, it would be really helpful.

Thanks in advance.

I would also like to ask, how would i make the current picture box which i am moving 'aware' of its surroundings? i.e. if i was moving a picture box and there was another picture box in front of it, it should automatically stop so it doesn't go over it etc.

Comment: _block.Bounds.IntersectsWith(block.Bounds)_ this is only testing itself and will always be true..

Comment: You need to calcualte the __next_- bounding rectangle before mvinf, then test against all other blocks and abort the ovement or stop it at the last allowed spot.

Comment: How would i do this?

Comment: It helps to have all PBoxes in a `List<PictureBox> boxes`. Then you can do the basic collision check in a `foreach (var box in boxes) if ( newbounds.IntersectsWith(box.Bounds) && box != movedBox) { hit = true; break; } ;` if hit don't allow the move.

Comment: Hey, i really appreciate the help, but i'm still persisting with issues. If it's not too much to ask, could you tweak my code for me? ill post the source. Thanks in advance. If you don't want to do it, i'd understand.

Comment: (I usually don't do this but looked at it..) - Hm, which problems do you have? It seems to work just fine..

Comment: Hey, yh it does some what work with the collision detection which came up with. However, there are too many bugs such as blocks still do go through each other in different directions. I was hoping you could implement the method you told me with List<PictureBox> boxes and then this foreach (var box in boxes) if ( newbounds.IntersectsWith(box.Bounds) && box != movedBox) { hit = true; break; } ;

Comment: _blocks still do go through each other in different directions._ I didn't see this. I'll try some more..

Comment: Great! i really do appreciate the time you've put in to helping me. Thank you for that, please do update me if you have found a solution.

Comment: Change the inner test to recognize the direction from which you hit: `if (block.Height == 55)
                        {
                            if (block.Left < blocks[i].Left)  // hit from left
                              block.Location = new Point( blocks[i].Left - block.Width - 6, block.Location.Y);
                            else
                              block.Location = new Point(blocks[i].Right + 6, block.Location.Y);
                        }`..

Comment: ..`else if (block.Width == 55)
                        {
                            if (block.Top < blocks[i].Top)  // hit from top
                              block.Location = new Point(block.Location.X, blocks[i].Top - block.Height - 4);
                            else 
                              block.Location = new Point(block.Location.X, blocks[i].Bottom + 4);
                        }
                        dragging = false;`

Comment: Note that there is a totally different approach: one can store the 'lastValidPosition' and upon detecting a collision simply reset the box to that position. However, in your case this would only work if you adapt the moving code as it creates invalid positions, which the check code then corrects; so all in all it would no neceassarily result in less lines, just a clearer layout of responsibilities.

Comment: Amazing! Thank you sooo much!! The solution you gave me to change the inner test to recognize the direction from which you hit it actually worked. All directions for collision detection is working perfectly now. Thanks again for the time and effort in helping me out. <3